# My Keras model doesn't convert to Tensorflow Lite without indicating errors

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, tflite

I have a Keras module that detects certain face grimaces and want it converted to tflite but it doesn't seem to work. I'm using Kaggle notebook and TensorFlow version: 2.15.0 & Keras version: 3.0.5

This is my model and it works fine before converting:

```
model = Sequential()

# Convolutional layers
# input_shape = (128, 128, 1)
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Flatten())

# Fully connected layers
model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Dense(256, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

# Output layer
model.add(Dense(output_class, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I saved the model in h5 format and loaded it on a new notebook to try if it works in a desperate attempt.

#### Imported modules:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import load_model
```

#### Loading the model:

This is working and it prints the expected message

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/kaggle/input/grimace-recognition/keras/grimace v1/1/grimace.h5')
print("loaded successfully")
```

#### Trying to convert the loaded model:

Then I'm passing the model to the tflite converter and it prints the first message "converter established" but then it stops and doesn't print the other message without showing any errors whatsoever and then I need to execute all the code blocks from the beginning in the notebook.

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
print("converter established")
tfmodel = converter.convert()
print("converted successfully")
open("grimace.tflite", "wb").write(tfmodel)
```

Note: that i'm planning using the tflite model in a flutter mobile application.

Comment: It can be due to a version mismatch. Can you share the h5 file link? I will take a look.

Comment: @mrtpk here you go: https://shorturl.at/uVX04
Any help would be great thanks